# Changing the web-root (or path-prefix) at runtime via servant?

Tags: haskell, servant

I need to give the ability to change the web-root (or path-prefix) of my API via CLI arguments.

If my server exposes the following API paths...

```
/enqueue
/run
/cancel
```

...at startup it should be possible to change them to the following by passing a CLI switch `--web-root=/admin`:

```
/admin/enqueue
/admin/run
/admin/cancel
```

The question is not related to parsing the command-line, which is a solved problem via `optparse-applicative`. It's about any in-built way in servant, **AT RUNTIME**, to (a) change the web-root of the server, and (b) make the corresponding change in various safe-links functions (generated via `allFieldLinks'`).

Comment: Perhaps [`rewritePureWithQueries `](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-extra-3.1.6/docs/Network-Wai-Middleware-Rewrite.html#v:rewritePureWithQueries) from [wai-extra](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-extra) could help. I don't think it will automatically rewrite outgoing links however.

Comment: There's a `Data.Reflection`-based solution to this, see here: https://github.com/alpmestan/servant-prefix/blob/master/servant-prefix.hs

Answer (score 1):

Servant provides no straightforward facility for doing this, and the internals of `Servant.Link` have been zealously overprotected (an unfortunately common problem with Haskell packages) so as to make it unnecessarily difficult to implement on the link side.

You *can* mount a servant API under a runtime-specified base path using the usual methods of specifying types at runtime.  However, getting safe links to automatically incorporate the base path seems close to impossible.  If you're satisfied with fixing up the links after the fact, then the following might work.

Given that you're using `allFieldLinks'`, you're probably using the generic interface, so suppose you have a service:

```
data HelloService route = HelloService
  { hello :: route :- "hello" :> Get '[PlainText] Text
  , world :: route :- "world" :> Get '[PlainText] Text
  } deriving (Generic)

helloServer :: HelloService AsServer
helloServer = HelloService
  { hello = return $ "Goto \"localhost:3000/" <> toUrlPiece (world asLink) <> "\""
  , world = return "Hello, world!"
  } where asLink = allFieldLinks
```

with the usual boring way of serving it at the root:

```
main = run 3000 $ genericServe helloServer
```

If you wanted to serve this off a compile-time base path (e.g., `/admin`) without modifying the service definition, you could rewrite `main` as:

```
main = run 3000 $ serve (Proxy @("admin" :> ToServant HelloService AsApi))
                        (genericServer helloServer)
```

To specify the base path component `"admin"` at runtime, you can define and case-match on an existential symbol:

```
main = do
  let base = "admin"
  case someSymbolVal base of
    SomeSymbol (_ :: Proxy base) ->
      run 3000 $ serve (Proxy @(base :> ToServant HelloService AsApi))
                       (genericServer helloServer)
```

This only allows one component in the base path, but you can generalize to a multiple-component base with:

```
serveUnder :: forall service. HasServer service '[]
  => [String] -> Proxy service -> Server service -> Application
serveUnder [] p s = serve p s
serveUnder (x:xs) _ s = case someSymbolVal x of
  SomeSymbol (_ :: Proxy x) -> serveUnder xs (Proxy @(x :> service)) s

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let base = ["foo", "bar"]  -- mount under /foo/bar
  run 3000 $ serveUnder (reverse base)
                        (genericApi (Proxy @HelloService))
                        (genericServer helloServer)
```

If you try this out and visit `http://localhost:3000/foo/bar/hello`, you'll see that the `allFieldLinks` doesn't reflect the new mount point.  If `Servant.Links` exposed more internals, this would be trivial to fix.  Unfortunately, as it is, the only reasonable way to address this is to pass some form of the runtime path into `helloServer` and have it fix the safe links as part of the rendering.

The resulting full program would look something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

module HelloService where

import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Servant
import Servant.API.Generic
import Servant.Server.Generic
import Network.URI
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp
import GHC.TypeLits

data HelloService route = HelloService
  { hello :: route :- "hello" :> Get '[PlainText] Text
  , world :: route :- "world" :> Get '[PlainText] Text
  } deriving (Generic)

helloServer :: Text -> HelloService AsServer
helloServer webroot = HelloService
  { hello = return $ "Goto \"localhost:3000/" <> renderLink (world asLink) <> "\""
  , world = return "Hello, world!"
  } where asLink = allFieldLinks
          renderLink l = webroot <> toUrlPiece l

serveUnder :: forall service. HasServer service '[]
  => [String] -> Proxy service -> Server service -> Application
serveUnder [] p s = serve p s
serveUnder (x:xs) _ s = case someSymbolVal x of
  SomeSymbol (_ :: Proxy x) -> serveUnder xs (Proxy @(x :> service)) s

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let base = ["foo", "bar"]  -- mount under /foo/bar
      webroot = "http://localhost:3000/" <> T.intercalate "/" (map escaped base) <> "/"
      escaped = T.pack . escapeURIString isUnreserved
  run 3000 $ serveUnder (reverse base)
                        (genericApi (Proxy @HelloService))
                        (genericServer (helloServer webroot))
```